# Unity Rigidbody3d jump height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and c#, i am trying to build my first game and i have a problem with my player(which is a cube) jumping. It seems like when i start a scene or the game The first jump is extremly high. but after reloading the scene or jumping some more the jump is like intended.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float forwardForce = 1000f;
    public float sideForce  = 100f;
    public float jumpForce = 2700f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.2f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public bool IsGrounded;
    public bool IsJumping;
    public float rotateAmount = 1f;
    public float boostSpeed = 500f;
    public float respawnBoarder = 8f;
   
    

     void Update() {
        if(IsGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
            rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        IsGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        rb.AddForce(0,0,forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKey("d")){
            rb.AddForce(sideForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("a")){
            rb.AddForce(-sideForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if(rb.position.y < -1f){
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }

        if(rb.position.x < -respawnBoarder){
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
        if(rb.position.x > respawnBoarder){
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKey("w")){
            
             rb.AddForce(0,0,boostSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotateAmount);  
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the jump is triggering more than once in some cases. If so, setting `IsGrounded` to `false` immediately after the jump may solve it, but to be honest I wonder whether the `IsGrounded` check in `FixedUpdate()` should additionally be checking whether the player is moving upwards or similar. It looks to me like `IsGrounded` could potentially be immediately reenabled if the player hasn't moved far enough away from the ground before the next `FixedUpdate()` rolls around.